# giving a string variable values conditional on another variable

Tags: stata

I am using Stata 14. I have US states and corresponding regions as integer. 
I want create a string variable that represents the region for each observation.
Currently my code is

```
gen div_name = "A"  
replace div_name = "New England" if div_no == 1     
replace div_name = "Middle Atlantic" if div_no == 2
.
.
replace div_name = "Pacific" if div_no == 9
```

..so it is a really long code.

I was wondering if there is a shorter way to do this where I can automate assigning values rather than manually hard coding them.

Answer (score 0):

You can define value labels in one line with `label define` and then use `decode` to create the string variable. See the `help` for those commands.

If the correspondence was defined in a separate dataset you could use `merge`. See e.g. [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/group-characteristics-for-subsets/)

There can't be a short-cut here other than typing all the names at some point or exploiting the fact that someone else typed them earlier into a file.

With nine or so labels, typing them yourself is quickest.

Note that you type one statement more than you need, even doing it the long way, as you could start

```
gen div_name = "New England" if div_no == 1
```